# Replace NA with NULL

Tags: r, null, na

I have a sample vector with NA, I want to replace these NA with NULL

```
ts<-c(12,NA,45,16,48,69,NA,3)
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
ts[is.na(ts)]<-NULL
```

is there anyway to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Cannot do it, NULL has special meaning, you could insert string "NULL".

Comment: Why not replace it using known and proven imputation methods?

Comment: but if i use string i'm not be able to use that vector for calculations(mean,median)<br/>

Comment: "NULL is not allowed in a vector.  When you attempt to set it as a value in a vector, it is it is quietly ignored... for any vector (matrix or array), NA represents a missing value.  NULL does not." (https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/ )

Comment: Why do you want to replace NA by NULL? For calculations like mean / median it should be way more safe to keep it and run e.g `mean(ts, na.rm=T)`. What behaviour do you expect if there is NULL instead of NA?

Comment: if i use this vector for a data frame and if i use `na.rm` it will remove entire row including other values. - @dom

Comment: what are those imputation methods which can replace NA - @NelsonGon

Comment: You can impute with mean,median,0 or use regression trees. Look at the `mice` package.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know a vector can't contain the value NULL. It will just get omitted.
For example

```
ts <- c(1,2,NULL,NULL)
ts
[1] 1 2
```

Why do you want to do this replacement in the first place?

Comment: Hi Julian,for some thing like mean ,median like operation 
and it's not omitted

> ts<-c(12,NA,45,16,48,69,NA,3)
> ts
[1] 12 NA 45 16 48 69 NA  3
> ts[2]
[1] NA

Comment: Just include a na.rm=T to your statements. Then NA values will be ignored

Comment: Im sorry Simonare, I wasn't aware of this restriction.

Comment: if i use this vector as a column for a data frame and if i use `na.rm` it will remove entire row including other values. - @Julian_Hn

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make it a real `NULL` but does the job.

```
forcats::fct_explicit_na(as.character(ts),"NULL")
```

Comment: Unfortunately yes!